# <interactive>:7:36: error: parse error on input `.' in command prompt using haskell ghci when my source file only has "Hello world" in it

Tags: haskell

[imge of errror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCCzp.png)

I'm very new to haskell and the entire installation process was confusing to me. I downloaded power shell and then installed chocolatey and haskell. now im putting ghci into my command prompt and trying to run my .hs file.

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see this question named [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Answer (score 2):

In order to load a file, you should work with the `:load` (or its shortcut `:l`) directive, so:

```
:load C:\Users\gravon\OneDrive\Desktop\yoo.hs
```

once you loaded the file, you can run a function, for example a `main`, given this function is defined in the `yoo.hs`.

You can also work with [**`runhaskell`** [haskell.org]](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/release/old/users-guide-0.1/x478.html#builders) and thus run a file in the shell with:

```
$ runhaskell 'C:\Users\gravon\OneDrive\Desktop\yoo.hs'
```